# backgroundworker works on one page but not another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i have background on a mvvm class binded to a view, within the mvvm constructor a made a backgroundworker sothat i can do some long events while the page is loaded.
that backgroundworker is working perfectly while running the program on my pc but on another pc it doesn't work.
also when i copied code implementing this backgroundworker with little changes to another page it didn't work in the second one and working in the first one !!!

```
    public CompoundsViewModel()
    {

        BackgroundWorker background = new BackgroundWorker();
        background.DoWork += BackgroundDoWork;
        background.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void BackgroundDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        FillCompounds();
        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

Actually the dowork event is fired in both cases, but the view didn't effected in one case and succeccfully effected in another one

Comment: You will have to share the `FillCompounds()` method - maybe something in there is the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by sharing it ?

Comment: `it doesn't work` what does that exactly mean? Throws an exception? Crashes? Have you tried debugging the code at all? `with little changes to another page` what changes? Your question is very vague. Please add more details.

Comment: no crashes, no exception, just the view did not effected with the events executed within the backgroundworker.
the changes is about the database tables used in FillCompounds()

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see what's happening in `FillCompounds()`?

Comment: i tried the break points and every thing is working perfectly with the debugging.

Comment: and the page is working perfectly in my pc but doesn't work in another one

Comment: Is FillCompounds() calling anything specific only available to your PC, such as database?

Comment: yes it is using the database, but the database works fine on both pcs
also when i did the same code directly without any backgroundworker it works

Comment: I think you need to share code in FillCompounds()

Comment: FillCompounds() is calling a function in the model executing some database work

Comment: return data from the db

Comment: ok, it was a silly mistake from me..
Sorry Guys :)

Comment: but the same problem is still .... why this is working on my pc and doesn't in another one ?